# Jquery toggle makes div's width jump when animating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having a problem when toggling the sidebar. When animating, the div's width jumps. I've tried to look for this problem, tried to apply `position: relative` on sidebar-wrapper, but it doesn't help. Also tried to remove some padding/margin,but it doesn't help. `overflow: hidden`, it still doesn't help.

Maybe I've missed something, so if you have any suggestions where specifically I should add/remove something I would be happy if you helped me, thx.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggle(1000);
});
```

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 20rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #2C2C2C 0%, #000000 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-left: 1px solid #707070;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.sidebar-container {
  border: 3px solid #D005C8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h-100 menu-collapse-button-div">
  <button id="menu-toggle">toggle<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
</div>

<!-- Right sidebar wrapper -->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush" id="right-side-bar">
    <div class="container sidebar-container mt-3 mb-3">helo</div>
    <div class="container sidebar-container mt-3 mb-3">hrwfw</div>
    <div class="container sidebar-container mt-3 mb-3">maaaaan</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just to be clear, the animation isn't entirely skipped, it animates kind of a half of its width, the rest is simply a jump.
**Using jquery-3.5.1-min.js**
Any kind of help/suggestions helps.

**EDIT:
Forgot to mention that both div's are inside one flexbox div. Might help**

Comment: I'm not seeing any "jump" in your snippet - do you have something else in your project code that is different?

Comment: @FluffyKitten already editted the question. Forgot to mention that these two divs are inside flexbox div (div that contains all other containers which I excluded - are not relative to this).

Comment: so you want the navbar to be in the viewport height?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see a jump, the whole black section is sliding smoothly to the left when I run the snippet.